# Determine if HashSet<String> contains a different cased string

Tags: c#, string, hashset, similarity, casing

I have a large set of strings, including many duplicates. It is important that all of the duplicates have the same casing. So this set would fail the test:

```
String[] strings = new String[] { "a", "A", "b", "C", "b" };
```

....but this test would pass:

```
String[] strings = new String[] { "A", "A", "b", "C", "b" };
```

As I iterate through each string in `strings`, how can my program see that `A` is a case-insensitive duplicate of `a` (and thus fail), but allow the duplicate `b` through?

Comment: Your title says `HashSet` and your question has `array`, is something missing ?

Comment: If you use `Equals` to check two strings for equality, there's an overload that takes in a `StringComparison` enum value. You might want to use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. If you need to make a `HashSet<string>` (or `Dictionary<string, X>`) use a specific comparison, construct the instance of `HashSet<>` (etc.) using the instance constructor that takes in an `IEqualityComparer<string>`. In this case you might want to use the comparer `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 4):

One simple approach would be to create *two* sets - one using a case-insensitive string comparer, and one using a case-sensitive one. (It's not clear to me whether you want a culture-sensitive string or not, or in which culture.)

After construction, if the two sets has a different size (`Count`) then there must be some elements which are equal by case-insensitive comparison, but not equal by case-sensitive comparison.

So something like:

```
public static bool AllDuplicatesSameCase(IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    var sensitive = new HashSet<String>(input, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
    var insensitive = new HashSet<String>(input, 
          StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    return sensitive.Count == insensitive.Count;
}
```

Comment: This will work because one comparer should be more "strict" than the other one, that is the logical implication _if_ `InvariantCulture` declares two strings to be equal, _then_ `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` will also declare them equal. There are two major issues to consider before choosing this solution. First, this creates two full copies of the source `input`. If the `input` is huge, this might be a waste of memory. Second, this iterates through the entire source twice. If there is a "counter-example" early in the `input` list, some other solutions might exit fast and not continue iterating.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Agreed. I was definitely going for simplicity over everything else.

Comment: Also note: If you create a `HashSet<string>` using the default `IEqualityComparer<string>`, you get an ordinal comparison (equivalent to `StringComparer.Ordinal`). This is distinct from the invariant culture. For example the invariant culture considers `"ss"` and `"ß"` equal.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Indeed - that's why I specified comparers in both sets :)

Answer (score 0):

You could check each entry explicitly.

```
static bool DuplicatesHaveSameCasing(string[] strings)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < strings.Length; ++j)
    {
      if (string.Equals(strings[i], strings[j], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        && strings[i] != strings[j])
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I chose to use ordinal comparison. Note that `!=` operator uses an ordinal and case-sensitive comparison. It is rather trivial to change this into some culture-dependent comparison.

Answer (score 0):

And another option using LINQ.

```
                    //Group strings without considering case
bool doesListPass = strings.GroupBy(s => s.ToUpper())
                    //Check that all strings in each group has the same case
                    .All(group => group.All(s => group.First() == s));

                    //Group strings without considering case
IEnumerable<string> cleanedList = strings.GroupBy(s => s.ToUpper())
                    //Check that all strings in each group has the same case
                    .Where(group => group.All(s => group.First() == s))
                    //Map all the "passing" groups to a list of strings 
                    .SelectMany(g => g.ToList());
```

Note: You can use ToUpper() or ToUpperInvariant() depending on your need.